# Is it necessary to update pom.properties and Manifest.MF files every time?

Tags: java, git, maven, github

I have two computer's that I have for when programming. One at work and my personal laptop. I do most of my work on my computer at work but when I try to synchronize my workspace on my personal laptop I always have two files sitting in the Git staging and I will always get an error when I try to do a pull request.

Error:

```
Checkout conflict with files: 
target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-
INF/maven/package/project/pom.properties
Checkout conflict with files: 
target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-
INF/maven/package/project/pom.properties
```

Manifest.MF (index)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: rle2016
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

Manifest.MF (local)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: Ryan
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_111
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

Obviously in here the difference is the built-by and build-jdk.

pom.properties (index)

```
#Generated by Maven Integration for Eclipse
#Wed Jun 14 15:55:40 EDT 2017
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
groupId=
m2e.projectName=Project
m2e.projectLocation=C\:\\Users\\rle2016\\git\\Project-Server
artifactId=Project
```

pom.properties (local)

```
#Generated by Maven Integration for Eclipse
#Tue Jun 27 22:52:06 EDT 2017
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
groupId=
m2e.projectName=Project
m2e.projectLocation=C\:\\Users\\Ryan\\workspace\\Project
artifactId=Project
```

And here the project locations are different.

So what I'm wondering is should I commit both of these files before I start working on anything? What I usually do is just do "Replace with HEAD Revision" on both of the files. Because if I commit the files wouldn't I just have the same issue when I change computers? I also don't want to do a commit just for these two files. I have changed some things in the code to some generic names.

Comment: The whole `target/` directory should be in .gitignore. They are build artifacts, not source code.

Comment: @1615903 Hey thanks for the response. Added to .gitignore!

Comment: @1615903 Hey I added the folder to .gitingore. I see it in in the file as "/target/" but the pom.properties file just came up again

Comment: gitignore only works on files that are not tracked, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/1615903

Answer (score 1):

according to your question , I suppose you use eclipse , you can use a gitignore template [Eclipse.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore) , that may solve your problem .

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. It seems like I'm unable to add these files to the ignore list